# Which constructor is used when an object is initialized with the result of an expression

Tags: c++

I have the following simple c++ code :

```
class X {
    public :
    int x ;
    X(int val) : x(val) {cout<<"one arg\n" ;} 
    X(const X&xx) {cout<<"const copy constr\n" ; x = xx.x ;}
    X(X&xx) {cout<<"non const copy constr\n" ; x = xx.x ;}
    X(const X&&xx) {cout<<"const move constr\n" ; x = xx.x ;}
    X(X&&xx) {cout<<"non const move constr\n" ; x = xx.x ;}
    X operator +(X &ob) {
        X xx(x+ob.x) ; cout<<"add\n" ; return xx ;
    }
    X operator=(const X &x) {cout<<"const assign\n" ;}
    X operator=(X &x) {cout<<"non const assign\n" ;}
    X operator=(const X &&x) {cout<<"const move assign\n" ;}
    X operator=(X &&x) {cout<<"non const move assign\n" ;}
} ;

main() {
    X   x1(10), x2(x1) ;
    cout<<"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n" ;
    X   x3 = x1+x2 ;//does not invoke move/copy constr ---> do not know why
    cout<<"###########"<<x3.x<<endl ;
    cout<<"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$\n" ;
    vector<X>   v ;
    v.push_back(X(100)) ;//invokes move constr
```

}

Via which constructor is the object **x3** created ?

Comment: one arg constructor.

Comment: "//does not invoke move/copy constr" I suspect copy ellision is the reason for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a bajillion duplicates of this question on stackoverflow, the move/copy is elided, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

As stated in the GCC FAQ (["My copy constructor doesn't run!"](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#copyelision)) when using gcc (or clang) compile with `-fno-elide-constructors` to see every intermediate temporary object getting copied or moved, but there's no reason to do that because it makes your program much slower.

What you're observing is that the `X` inside `operator+` is constructed at the  stack location reserved for `x3`, and so there is no copy or move needed because an `X` with  the right value has already been constructed at the right location. If you print out the address of `xx` and the address of `x3` you will see they are the same object.